# How to Update Snake 2D body properbly

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine, 2d-games

I am programming a Snake-like Game for School.
The thing is I am not using a 2D Array or something for the position, 
instead my snake is a free moving object in a 2D environment. It is like for example Stardew Valley.

My Problem is:
I am updating the Body following the snake like this:

```
public void tick(float x, float y, char direction) {

    counterx += Math.abs(xt - x);
    countery += Math.abs(yt - y);
    this.direction = direction;

    if(counterx > Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH) {
        switch(this.direction) {
        case DIRECTION_UP:
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y + Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT;
            break;
        case DIRECTION_DOWN:
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y - Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT;
            break;
        case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
            this.x = x - Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH;
            this.y = y;
            break;
        case DIRECTION_LEFT:
            this.x = x + Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH;
            this.y = y;
            break;
        }
        counterx = 0;
    } else if(countery > Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT) {
        switch(this.direction) {
        case DIRECTION_UP:
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y + Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT;
            break;
        case DIRECTION_DOWN:
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y - Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT;
            break;
        case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
            this.x = x - Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH;
            this.y = y;
            break;
        case DIRECTION_LEFT:
            this.x = x + Creature.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH;
            this.y = y;
            break;
        }
        countery = 0;
    }

    tDirection = this.direction;
    next.tick(this.x, this.y, this.tDirection);
    xt = this.x;
    yt = this.y;
}
```

The tick() Method is called constantly and the x and y position, as well as the direction, is given from the Object calling the Method. The Snakehead which is controlled with WASD calls the Method the first time and then every Snake Part is calling the next one.

[Snake with early development graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np18S.png)
Every SnakeTile is 32 by 32.

**The thing is** the body changes direction with the head instantly and I do not know how to change this.
I tried timers for only updating every few seconds and so on.

Right now (like in the code) I am only updating when the direction count of 1 Tile is traveled and now when I look closely I can see that the Snake is snaping, but it is much to fast so you can only see it IF you can see it 1 frame each time.

So can anyone help me with a concept or something?

It would be totally awesome because I am not getting any further...

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is because every parts of your snake is transmitting the head direction to the next part.

To do it,  your snake body part have to remember their last move.  It s that last move that have to be passed to the next part.

You can achieve it by creating a Body class.

Or you can simply use a list as long as your snake to store these positions.

On another subject,  you said : The thing is I am not using a 2D Array or something for the position, instead my snake is a free moving object in a 2D environment

Well in fact it's exactly the same thing.  only the "2d" array is as wide and high as your screen resolution is.  You can see your screen as a 2d array and do the exact same method or technique to solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

Actually, in the End, I tried to write Direction changes to a HashMap whenever the head changed direction with the coordinates as key and the direction as value. 

Then the snake parts would check if there is a marker on their position and if so change their direction. 
The Markers would get removed by the SnakeEnd. In my head, it worked so I implemented it, but I got a confusing bug and ran out of time so I talked to my teacher and he was also not able to solve it so he agreed to not judge that part of my software and in the end, I got an A :)